# Graphs, non-Hausdorfness and Wallman compactifications of non-regular spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, graph-theory

Given a non-Hausdorff space $X$, one can form a graph $G_X$: vertices the points of $X$, edges indicating point pairs not separated by open sets.  Up to graph-theoretically (but not topologically) isolated points, I believe one can achieve any graph as a  $G_X$ just by realizing edges with copies of the so-called bug-eyed line.

Hausdorffness can fail for the Wallman compactification $\gamma X$ of a Hausdorff, but not normal, space $X$.  As such, do there exist graph-theoretic constrains on the non-isolated points of$ G_{\gamma X}$?

Comment: Reminder: the Wallman compactification consists of ultrafilters in the lattice of closed sets.